# struct uninitialization issue in c++

Tags: c++11, gcc, struct, initialization, list-initialization

I have following three structs definitions, for `SA, SBad, SC`, I simplified name and members to just demonstrate the issue.

```
 struct SA {
     int snap;
 };

 template <int W> class VString
 {
     char data[W];
   public:
     VString() { }
 };

 struct SBad {
     VString<9> s;
     int i;
 };

 struct SC {
     int inst;
 };
```

And I have a containing struct to hold data from the network which consists of the above structures:

```
 struct S {
     std::vector<SA>           m_a;
     SBad                      m_bad;
     std::vector<SC>           m_c;
 };
```

And in the code I need to reset struct frequently, with:

```
// data member
S m_s;
// member function
void clear() {
   m_s.m_bad   = {};
}
```

I'm using gcc version 7.3.1. With debug build, this works fine, with release build, it fails with:

```
error: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
```

The gcc flag is:

```
-std=c++11 -O3 -Werror -Wall
```

Why is this error, it is a defined way of initialising data to zero, right?
If I change to :

```
void clear() {
    SA sa{};
    m_s.a = sa;
    m_s.b = {};
    ...
}
```

instead, the release build will succeed.

UPDATE:

I created a [minimum working test case](https://godbolt.org/z/z2rbyb) to show the issue.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example where we can see the error

Comment: It only contains data member, no function members.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the full error message

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/JdoQV9). There is nothing "used" nor anything "anonymous" in the code you posted. The error is likely caused by code you did not post

Comment: ok, i'm making a test case for this.

Comment: i updated with test case, any thoughts? @Thrasher

Comment: the test case reliably reproduce the error @idclev463035818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use curly-brace initialization with "Aggregates". Quoting the standard:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) **with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static
> data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual
> functions (10.3).**
>
> ...
>
> When an aggregate is initialized the initializer can contain an
> initializer-clause consisting of a **brace-enclosed**, comma-separated
> list of initializer-clauses for the members of the aggregate, written
> in increasing subscript or member order. If the aggregate contains
> subaggregates, this **rule applies recursively** to the members of the
> subaggregate.

In your case, `SBad` is *not* an aggregate because `SBad::s` of type `VString` is *not* an aggregate since you defined a constructor for `VString`. To get your code to work, drop the constructor of `VString`:

```
 template <int W> class VString {
     char data[W];
 };
```

Try it here: https://godbolt.org/z/TTonr6

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the issue is in this ctor, but gcc gives error about other fields which was quite misleading...